# restore functionality in InApp android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, restore

I have implemented Inapp Billing in my app. For that i have used buttons. when i click button it goes to the purchase activity and it purchases the product. once it purchases the product the button will be invisible. and the other button will be visible which will allow the user to open the product. It is all happening perfectly.But when i reopen the app again the button for purchase is visible . i do not want the button to be visible once it is purchased. how to make the button invisible once it is used for successful purchase.

StartUpActivity.java

```
public class StartUpActivity extends PurchaseActivity implements   OnIabSetupFinishedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Log.d("App started");
}
@Override
public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        Log.d("In-app Billing set up" + result);
        dealWithIabSetupSuccess();
    } else {
        Log.d("Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
        dealWithIabSetupFailure();
    }
}
@Override
protected void dealWithIabSetupSuccess() {
    navigate().toMainActivity();
    finish();
}
@Override
protected void dealWithIabSetupFailure() {
    popBurntToast("Sorry In App Billing isn't available on your device");
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BlundellActivity implements MainMenu {
public Button topicsbutton;
public Button mediabutton;
public Button purchasetopicsbutton;
public Button purchasemediabutton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    topicsbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1a);
    mediabutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2a);
    purchasetopicsbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    purchasemediabutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
}
@Override
public void onTopicsPurchaseItemClick(View v) {
    navigate().toPurchaseTopicsActivityForResult();
}
@Override
public void onMediaPurchaseItemClick(View v) {
    navigate().toPurchaseMediaActivityForResult();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (Navigator.REQUEST_TOPICS_PURCHASE == requestCode) {
        if (RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
            dealWithSuccessfulTopicsPurchase();
        } else {
            dealWithFailedTopicsPurchase();
        }
    }        else if (Navigator.REQUEST_MEDIA_PURCHASE == requestCode) {
        if (RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
            dealWithSuccessfulMediaPurchase();
        } else {
            dealWithFailedMediaPurchase();
        }
    }
}
public void dealWithSuccessfulTopicsPurchase() {
    Log.d("Topics purchased");
    popToast("Topics purchased");
    topicsbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    purchasetopicsbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
private void dealWithSuccessfulMediaPurchase() {
    Log.d("Media purchased");
    popToast("Media purchased");
    mediabutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    purchasemediabutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
private void dealWithFailedTopicsPurchase() {
    Log.d("Topics purchase failed");
    popToast("Failed to purchase Topics");
}
private void dealWithFailedMediaPurchase() {
    Log.d("Media purchase failed");
    popToast("Failed to purchase Media");
}
public void TopicsOpen(View v) {
    navigate().toTopicsopen();
}
public void MediaOpen(View v) {
    navigate().toMediaopen();
}
}
```

PurchaseActivity.java

```
 public abstract class PurchaseActivity extends BlundellActivity implements OnIabSetupFinishedListener, OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener {
private IabHelper billingHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    billingHelper = new IabHelper(this, AppProperties.BASE_64_KEY);
    billingHelper.startSetup(this);
}
@Override
public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        Log.d("In-app Billing set up" + result);
        dealWithIabSetupSuccess();
    } else {
        Log.d("Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
        dealWithIabSetupFailure();
    }
}
protected abstract void dealWithIabSetupSuccess();
protected abstract void dealWithIabSetupFailure();
protected void purchaseItem(String sku) {
    billingHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, sku, 123, this);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    billingHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
@Override
public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {
    if (result.isFailure()) {
        dealWithPurchaseFailed(result);
    } else if (Items.SKU1.equals(info.getSku())) {
        dealWithTopicsPurchaseSuccess(result, info);
    }
    else if (Items.SKU2.equals(info.getSku())) {
        dealWithMediaPurchaseSuccess(result, info);
    }
    finish();
}
protected void dealWithPurchaseFailed(IabResult result) {
    Log.d("Error purchasing: " + result);
}
protected void dealWithTopicsPurchaseSuccess(IabResult result, Purchase info) {
    Log.d("Item purchased: " + result);
}
protected void dealWithMediaPurchaseSuccess(IabResult result, Purchase info) {
    Log.d("Item purchased: " + result);
    billingHelper.consumeAsync(info, null);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    disposeBillingHelper();
    super.onDestroy();
}
private void disposeBillingHelper() {
    if (billingHelper != null) {
        billingHelper.dispose();
    }
    billingHelper = null;
}
}
```

Comment: What in-app billing version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the API version 3 you can call [getPurchases()](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases) method at the `onCreate()`.

> This method returns the current un-consumed products owned by the user.

That means if your product is un-consumable, i.e, user will only buy it once then you will have your necessary info right here.

Can't explain how to do it better than in official documentation. Take a look at the [Querying for Purchased Items](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases) topic to have a code example.

Basically you will receive a list of `ownedSkus` (owned product ID's) and all you have to do is a loop over this list and make your buttons invisible/ visible.

Let me know if this what you was looking for :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. i will try the way you have explained. I am using IAB 3

Comment: Yes ia m using API version3 . i have two buttons for two products. how to disable these two buttons permanently once the item is purchased. But i am not sure how to implement the getPurchase() method. when i try to use the code given at Querying for purchase item. i am getting the error at mservice as  " mService can't be resolved". Can you please help me with some more details. In which java class i need to call this method. can you help me with some code

Comment: @user1903270, I guess something is missing! How did you do to buy content, I mean, where did you put all the code that allows you to buy something?

Comment: The remaining code is as it is from the sample code from google.

Comment: Humm, take a better look to the `onCreate()` method from the sample code. There will be a line `mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);` and this parameter is the responsible listener to return to you all the info you need... It's very easy to understand the mechanism looking to the sample. Let me know how you go!

Comment: Sorry the example code is not from the google,i got confused it is from here : https://github.com/blundell/SimpleInAppPurchaseV3.  May be you can help me in a much better way.Thanks

Comment: Thanks to every one . I have solved the issue by using the example code from google.